# Carousel slicing and webpage fade in effects?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I been searching all over for an examples or tutorials on how to do slicing carousels and fade in effects (from left, right, top, or bottom) for sections of website.  Check this website https://www.gracethemes.com/demo/wedding-bells/ to see what I am asking. CSS or Javascript ways are good.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think its [Nivo Slider](https://docs.themeisle.com/article/487-nivo-slider-settings)

Comment: I just double checked, yes, code from page you provided is Nivo Slider. I hope I helped.

Comment: I want to code it myself.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. It shows no research effort. Please try it yourself first, then ask a more specific question.

Comment: Tip: write 'debugger' in your console to pause the animations.

Comment: What is happening is that some `div`'s are being shown over the normal image. The background-image is placed in a way that it overlaps the other image. Then the overlapping `div`'s width/height is animated. Then the background image is replaced with the new image. Then it repeats the process.